# Where to add tax credit values

Tags: taxes

I am first time user of CiviCRM and have a specific question.

Where I can add/edit values for Tax Credit?
Previous Admin has left and I have to update the Tax Credit values for current year.

Answer (score 2):

What jurisdiction are you in? Countries typically have their own requirements for issuing Tax Receipts for Eligible Donations.

In CiviCRM the Financial Type determines whether a Contribution of that Financial Type is deductible for income tax purposes or not. A contribution with multiple financial types can then become partially Tax Receiptable -> e.g. Meal$ (not eligible) + Donation$ (eligible).

The non-deductible amount field (hit Edit Contribution to find it) -> is handy if you need to make manual adjustments.

Of course it still depends on the Code you use to generate the Tax Receipts how exactly it processes the line-items and the non-deductible amount field. We do that in our Canadian CDN Tax Receipts Extension.

Hope that helps you along.

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you for your input.
Financial types and Accounts are all setup, its all working for years, all I need is to change the values to reflect new tax credits as per law. (previous person used to change these values every year)

On our site when user click donation amount it shows tax credit to the use, I have to upload new values but I am not able to find where those values would be stored.

Comment: This is not a native CiviCRM Core workflow - so you really need to find your previous admin to figure out how/what custom code may be in place that handles this for your project.